# google games turn-based invitation is wrongly recognized as a INVITATION_TYPE_REAL_TIME

Tags: android, google-play-games

From device A, I am sending a Turn-based invitation to device B. But device B, although receives the invitation, it wrongly recognizes it as a real-time invitation! And obviously this is a problem and I can't continue with the game!

I'm sending the invitation from device A like this:

```
TurnBasedMatchConfig.Builder matchBuilder = TurnBasedMatchConfig.builder();

int minP = 1;
int maxP = 1;
int bitMask = 0;
int variant = -1;
ArrayList<String> invitees = ....list of players here...

if (minP > 0 && maxP > 0)
{
    matchBuilder.setAutoMatchCriteria(RoomConfig.createAutoMatchCriteria(
                        minP,
                        maxP,
                        bitMask));
}

matchBuilder.setVariant(variant);

if (invitees.size() > 0) matchBuilder.addInvitedPlayers(invitees);

Games.TurnBasedMultiplayer.createMatch(_client, matchBuilder.build()).setResultCallback(new InitiateMatchResultClass());
```

And on device B I get the invitation like this: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/OnInvitationReceivedListener

```
@Override
public void onInvitationReceived(Invitation invitation)
{
    Log.i(ExConsts.TAG, "onInvitationReceived");

    if(invitation.getInvitationType() == Invitation.INVITATION_TYPE_REAL_TIME)
        {
            Log.i(ExConsts.TAG, "INVITATION_TYPE_REAL_TIME");
        }
        else if(invitation.getInvitationType() == Invitation.INVITATION_TYPE_TURN_BASED)
        {
            Log.i(ExConsts.TAG, "INVITATION_TYPE_TURN_BASED");
        }
}
```

What am I possibly doing wrong?!

Comment: Looking at this [sample code by Google](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/blob/master/BasicSamples/SkeletonTbmp/src/main/java/com/google/example/tbmpskeleton/SkeletonActivity.java),
did you add your OnInvitationReceivedListener() ?

Comment: I'm NOT saying that the listener is not called! onInvitationReceived does work. The problem is that it says the invitation type is a real-time and that's wrong!

Comment: Did you follow the turn-based step by step [tutorial provided in the GPGS docs](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/turnbasedMultiplayer)?